# How to call object function from Typescript object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to call a function on a Date object from TypeScript, but it won't allow me to. I'm doing this in an an if/else and I've eliminated the other two allowed primitive types. I just don't know how to use the object type from TypeScript. None of the functions available on the TypeScript object seems to be appropriate.
Here's the code:

```js
const formatDate = (date: string | number | object): string | null => {
    if (typeof date === 'string') return date ? new Date(date).toISOString() : null;
    else if (typeof date == 'number') return date != null ? new Date(date).toISOString() : null;
    else if (date.hasOwnProperty('toISOString')) return date.toISOString();
    else return null;
}
```

I get the error:

```
TS2339: Property 'toISOString' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Is there any way to call an object's function from Typescript object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript cannot assure type safety as you just stated that date is a random object. To fix that, you could either use the Date type or create an interface matching the method you need:

```
interface hasIsoString {
  toISOString: () => string
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I did see that in the egghead videos. I just forgot about it. BTW, I did use the Date type, but I get the same error.

Comment: I tried Date again, and it works now. I probably had some other problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `date` *doesn't* have `toISOString` as its own property. The `toISOString()` method is attached to the prototype of the `Date` constructor, not any given `Date` object.

```
(new Date()).hasOwnProperty('toISOString')   //false
Date.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toISOString') //true
```

Regardless, though, you don't need that third check to ensure type safety. Typescript will already treat it as a date after the first two type guards by process of elimination:

```
const formatDate = (date: string | number | Date) => {
    if (typeof date === 'string') return date ? new Date(date).toISOString() : null;
    else if (typeof date == 'number') return date != null ? new Date(date).toISOString() : null;
    return date.toISOString();
}

formatDate('2017-11-10');              //"2017-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
formatDate(1510300800000);             //"2017-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
formatDate(new Date(2017, 10, 10));    //"2017-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
formatDate({ foo: 'bar' });            //not allowed
```

If, however, you're somehow going to be making the compiled code available in a non-Typescript environment, you could in theory change your third check like so, just to be safe:

```
const formatDate = (date: string | number | Date) => {
    if (typeof date === 'string') return date ? new Date(date).toISOString() : null;
    else if (typeof date == 'number') return date != null ? new Date(date).toISOString() : null;
    else if (date instanceof Date) return date.toISOString();
    return null;
}

formatDate('2017-11-10');              //"2017-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
formatDate(1510300800000);             //"2017-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
formatDate(new Date(2017, 10, 10));    //"2017-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
formatDate({ foo: 'bar' });            //still not allowed, but would return null if it were
```

Also note that in either case you don't need to explicitly specify the return type on this function - Typescript will figure it out for you.